# Single dispatch by value methodes…

Tags: python-3.x, enums, single-dispatch

I am reading some binary data from a serial port. Each packet can contain a wide array (a couple of dozen or so) messages identified by specific byte sequences. To make matter simple, let us assume only one bye so that `0x01` corresponds to the first message and so on. I want to be able to call a `process` method to deal with each message. I could have a long and tedious if loop but that would be horrid. A `singledispatch` seems like a much nicer option but a class per message seems OO gone made as well as getting back to the huge if loop for creating those.

So, I need a single dispatch by value of `bytearray` working on methods.

Something like thus:

```
from functools import singledispatch


class Ook(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.process = singledispatch(self.process)
        self.process.register(bytearray([0x01]), self.process_msg_one)  # FIXME!
        self.process.register(bytearray([0x02]), self.process_msg_two)  # FIXME!

    def process(self, arg):
        raise TypeError("Message is not supported.")

    def process_msg_one(self, arg):
        print(arg)

    def process_msg_two(self, arg):
        print(arg)
```

I am well aware of [Łukasz Langa's blog post](http://lukasz.langa.pl/8/single-dispatch-generic-functions/) but his implementation of dispatch by value uses `Enum` as a base class. My real `Ook` class inherits from an abstract class (so I can have a simulator instead of real hardware) and mixing it with `Enum` raises `TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its base`…